# Use same router schema for all models in Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Assuming I have **Node.JS** app composed of 3 models : *project*, *task*, *user*.
I want to create routes for these models, but with the same router schema :

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function (entity) {
    router.route('/:entity_id')
    .get(get_entity);

    var get_entity = function (req, res) {
        res.send(entity + req.params.entity_id);
    };

    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.send(entity);
    });

    return router;
};
```

My solution was to read files into */models* directory, and create an instance of the router for files found :

```
var path= require('path');
var fs= require('fs');
var modelsDir= fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '../models'));
modelsDir.forEach(function (model) {
    if (model.indexOf('.js') > -1) {
        var modelName = model.substr(0, model.length-3);
        app.use('/'+modelName, require('./api/global')(modelName));
    }
});
```

When I launch the app, something strange; Here are my outputs in the browser :

- /project --> "project"
- /project/2 --> "project2"
- /task --> "project"
- /task/2 --> "project2"
- /user --> "project"

I guess the router was made when first `app.use()` was invoked (for *project*), then express app uses this router for new paths given (*task*,*user*). But how can I programmatically define a router for each models ? (I have fifty different models...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put `var router = express.Router();` inside `module.exports` function

the router is the same object, when you call it for the second time, it'll override the previous implementation, when you put the declaration inside, every time the function is called, a new instance is created without overriding the previous one

Comment: Indeed, any explanation ? :)

Comment: sorry about that, just edited my answer, if you don't understand something leave a comment :)